Add thumbnail to .mp4 video file
How would I add/change a thumbnail on an mp4 file in Android Studio? The code I already have:
val videoUri = Uri.Builder().scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE).path(R.raw.test_video.toString()).build()

val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
    .setUri(videoUri).build()

val editedMediaItem = EditedMediaItem.Builder(mediaItem).apply {
    setRemoveAudio(true)
}.build()

val transformer = Transformer.Builder(baseContext).build()
transformer.start(editedMediaItem, file)


MP4 file format doesn't have a section for putting thumbnails. If you have a file that shows a custom picture in your device and want to recreate, then share such an example MP4 file, for advice about how to match its bytes setup... Or else forget MP4 and put your audio/video data inside MOV file format instead (it has a covr section to put JPG or PNG bytes)
